# My counter counts up instead of down

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, adobe

My counter is counting up instead of down? I like it to count down from 10 minutes and when hours is 0 and minutes is 0 and seconds is 0 I want it to remove the counter and it should go to another frame using gotoAndStop(2).

```
var countdownTimer:Timer = new Timer(1000);

countdownTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, updateTime);

countdownTimer.start();


var startTime:int = getTimer();

function updateTime(e:TimerEvent):void


{


// milliseconds passed
var timePassed:int = getTimer()-startTime;
var seconds:Number = Math.floor(timePassed / 1000);
var minutes:Number = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
var hours:Number = Math.floor(minutes / 60);


seconds %= 60;
minutes %= 60;
hours %= 24;

var sec:String = seconds.toString();
var min:String = minutes.toString();
var hrs:String = hours.toString();


if (sec.length < 2) {
    sec = "0" + sec;
}

//A zero will automatic be put to the right side og 1, so "1" will be "10"

if (min.length < 2) {
    min = "1" + min;
}

if (hrs.length < 2) {
    hrs = "0" + hrs;
}

var time:String = hrs + ":" + min + ":" + sec;

time_txt.text = time;
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22141106/as-3-flash-countdown-timer-for-game-over-screen

Comment: @EastonBornemeier  Thanks for your reply but the answers in that thread didn't make any sense to me.

Comment: Because you display **getTimer() - startTime**. Variable **startTime** is fixed. Function **getTimer()** returns value in milliseconds since application start, which means each time you call it the result is equal or greater than the last time. Thus **getTimer() - startTime** goes up. Always.

Answer (score 2):

Like Organis said :) You need to substract the time passed from your 10 minutes.

```
private var TOTAL_TIME:int = 10 * 60 * 1000; // 10 minutes or 600000 milliseconds

var timePassed:int = getTimer()-startTime;
var timeLeft:int = TOTAL_TIME - timePassed;

// use timeLeft for the display, not timePassed
var seconds:Number = Math.floor(timeLeft / 1000);
```